# Javascript open new tab cognos authoring perspective mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, cognos

I am using cognos share link in javascript,

- open _self working
- open _top working
- open _parent working
- open href using mouse middle click working

> **open _blank does not work**

```
function routeLink(urlValue) {
    window.open(urlValue,"_blank");
    window.focus();
}
```

browser = Google Chrome 57.0.2987
pop-up blocker disable for all website

SAMPLE URL = http://{ip}:{port}/bi/?perspective=authoring&pathRef={path}&ui_appbar=false&ui_navbar=false&action=run&format=HTML&prompt=true

RESPONSE={"code:"UPS-ERR-009","level":"error","description":"The requested credential object was not found","message":"The request credential object was not found."}

NOTE:cognos perspective=dashboard link working _blank mode

Answer (score 1):

In another tab of the browser, login to the cognos server. In this way cookies,session will be set in the browser. Then the javascript call should work, or atleast it should be able to find the credentials

Comment: Thank you for return. We used SSO so i don't try your answer. I fixed workaround right click -> open new tab.